# How to call exec url?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am just viewing the spread sheet. When I am trying to call development url its working and when I try to call exec url that gives error

> Uncaught Error: "Sheets" is not defined in exec mode.

```
function myFunction() 
{
      doGet();
}
function LoadSpreadSheetData() {
    var mydataar = '';
      var spreadsheetId = 'spreadsheetId';
      var rangeName = 'B2:G';
      var values = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadsheetId, rangeName).values;
      if (!values) {
        Logger.log('No data found.');
      } else {
        Logger.log('Name, Major:');
        for (var row = 0; row < values.length; row++) {

          // values[row][0];
          // Print columns A and E, which correspond to indices 0 and 4.
          Logger.log(' - %s,', values[row][0]);
          mydataar =mydataar+'<tr>'+
                    '<td>'+values[row][0]+'</td>'+
                    '<td>'+values[row][1]+'</td>'+
                    '<td>'+values[row][2]+'</td>'+
                    '<td>'+values[row][3]+'</td>'+
                    '<td>'+values[row][4]+'</td>'+
                    '<td>'+values[row][5]+'</td>'+
                '</tr>';
          //alert(values[row][0]);
        }
      }
      return mydataar;
    }

    function doGet() {
      return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
    }
```

The issue is shown here:

[image]

Comment: Is the Sheets API enabled in the Apps Script GUI **and** in the Google API Console?

Comment: @DimuDesigns Yes I enabled both and it is working for testing url given .. but not working for the exce url.

Comment: Try redeploying the Web App, but as new version (not update). There is a known issue with Web App where changes to the code only take hold when a new project version is created.

Comment: Thanks @DimuDesigns IT worked for me...